# Safari full screen bug

Tags: flash, safari, fullscreen

I need to use full screen mode in my flash application, for some reason when i go into full screen mode in safari or chrome, the stage is completely disabled. I tried using a very clean swf file with nothing on it, just 2 buttons: one for full screen and the other for normal screen, and still i can't click on anything after going into full mode. In IE and FF everything works fine, any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure but I think it could have something to do with your [wmode](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=e5141) setting:

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
```

Comment: this newbie may not know how to accept answer :p So I upvote you as part of the "accept" point